# Generics for corresponding sub-types of union types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

Let's say I have a union type that I am using with a reducer-like pattern for API calls that looks something like this:

```js
type Action = {
    request: {
        action: "create user",
        payload: { name: string, age: number },
    },
    response: { ok: true, message: "user created" },
} | {
    request: {
        action: "delete user",
        payload: { id: number },
    },
    response: { ok: true, message: "user deleted" },
};
```

When I choose a particular action, I want to be able to predict what the corresponding response will be with type safety. For example, if I were to make a function like this, I want to enforce that I am indeed returning the proper corresponding response for every request. I am not having a trouble with type safety on the input types. I am having trouble linking the output to the corresponding sub-type related to the input type.

```js
function doAction<T extends Action>(request: T["request"]): T["response"] {
    if (request.action === "create user") {
        const userName = payload.user.name; // Here we're good for type safety 
        return {
            ok: true,
            message: "user deleted", // This should error, but it doesn't 
        };
    } else {
        const { id } = request.payload; // Again, we're good here for type safety 
        return {
            ok: true,
            message: "user deleted", // Ok, but missing strong type safety here  
        }; 
    }
}
```

How can I indicate that I want the `["response"]` part of the object type chosen in the `["request"]`, and not just any `Action["response"]`?

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQN4FgBQURUAThAI4CuEAzsAFw4HEtQCGCKqjARHGW2DRKNCCR4AaZqyJg2IADbI2AE0bYoqNgFsIjOiUSoA5hPbG9mytoBGYqAF8phYk+lEyNMGlHqoyAGtGYBJqM10aGjYLXhF7fghBCBUeR2cHKAAfJhcPCmo6dXdWDiQ0XhUIBQghKDjxZxlZeSVVP0Q1K1t7N1y04s9vVF8cfyCoELCoCKiYqB56qErqoRT+-AcAbgICADNKVE40JeR4MtQAHgAVKAgADyFUFRpYI9QAPgAKMipaBigrgBtHg-ArAHgAXQAlIwgSDaENRJCcixELsoN98n8AHSlLiYDBYPgCWr1HhQlFNMjASgkdAaQLBUIQcK0WaWBaiEhLKo1ZKpLZQAD0QoBAAtEC8aGLkJQFCpbiQSMgSGZEMAAOQvVDIYATMXQbSCOASkykBE+CDFDJVUSUmTU2n0sZMqYzaIcxbLPlrQUi8WSqDS2XyqB2MZqvWB4AG6bG03Gc1eS1Qa0EBw7fBAA)

I would also like to be able to link these two corresponding halves of the object when making middleware functions like this, for example:

```js
function<T extends Action>(req: Request<T["request"]>, res: Response<T["response"]>) {
    if (req.body.action === "create user") {
        res.send({ ok: true, message: "user deleted" }); // this should not be allowed
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reduce complexity and increase type safety it worth using here `strategy pattern`.

Consider this example:

```js
type Action = {
    request: {
        action: "create user",
        payload: { name: string, age: number },
    },
    response: { ok: true, message: "user created" },
} | {
    request: {
        action: "delete user",
        payload: { id: number },
    },
    response: { ok: true, message: "user deleted" },
};

type Strategy = {
    [Prop in Action['request']['action']]: Extract<Action, { request: { action: Prop } }>['response']
}

const strategy: Strategy = {
    'create user': { ok: true, message: "user created" },
    'delete user': { ok: true, message: "user deleted" }
};

function doAction<T extends Action['request']>(request: T): Extract<Action, { request: T }>['response']
function doAction(request: Action['request']) {
    return strategy[request.action]

}

// {
//     ok: true;
//     message: "user created";
// }
const createUser = doAction({
    action: "create user",
    payload: { name: 'string', age: 42 },
})


// {
//     ok: true;
//     message: "user deleted";
// }
const deleteUser = doAction({
    action: "delete user",
    payload: { id: 1 },
})
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7KXEN)

`Strategy` - creates hash map data structure where key is an action name and value is a return type of your function.

Also, I have [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) `doAction` function in order to narrow return type.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll accept this answer soon unless someone else has a way to do this without the `strategy pattern` ? The only problem with this is I can't see a way to make it enforce the response type based on the request if I were to use it in a middleware function like if I were using `next-connect` and I wanted to make a handler initialized with generics for the request and return types. `const handler = nc<ReqType, ResType>({ ...` would there be any way of linking those two types there??

Comment: So it seems the only way to enforce the proper output of the function is to use the `strategy pattern` ?

Comment: @AdamD could you pelase provide an example with `next-connect` ? I'm not familar with this. Apart from that, AFAIK, strategy pattern is the simpliest one and does not require you to use any sort of type assertions. However, feel free to wait for other answers. I'm perfectly fine if you will not accept my answer. I;mt not interested in stackoverflow point system. I;m more into some interesting type exercises. [Here](https://catchts.com/) you can find a lot of interesting examples